# Can't do yum install postfix on Fedora 20

Tags: linux, fedora

I have this problem when trying to install "postfix". I've done some research and tried commenting out "metalink" line and uncommenting "baseurl" line in the file /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo

Still, problem persists. [image]

This is what I have in /etc/sysconfig/network:

```
NETWORKING=yes 
HWADDR=52:54:00:52:28:37 
HOSTNAME=vm02.mdtrinh.org 
GATEWAY=192.168.22.1 
IPADDR=192.168.22.203 
DNS1=192.168.22.2 
DNS2=8.8.8.8 
ONBOOT=yes
```

Comment: You seem to be unable to resolve the repos, which points to networking issues.  Can you ping? First by IP address (try `8.8.8.8`) then by name.
Also, try to paste output as text instead of using screen-shots.

Comment: I can't ping by IP address and by name. This is what I have in /etc/sysconfig/network: `NETWORKING=yes
HWADDR=52:54:00:52:28:37
HOSTNAME=vm02.mdtrinh.org
GATEWAY=192.168.22.1
IPADDR=192.168.22.203
DNS1=192.168.22.2
DNS2=8.8.8.8
ONBOOT=yes`

Comment: You need to fix that first. Try to ping your GATEWAY.  Also, add useful info such as the content of `/etc/sysconfig/network` to your question - it will be much easier for others to find it there than to have to sieve through all the comments to find it :-)

Comment: pinging my gateway works.

Comment: The next hop will (I guess) be your router. Try to ping that.  If that fails, you'll need to check the NAT and/or firewall on the host.

Comment: I have no idea why I could install postfix on the other vm

Comment: If it works on another VM, then it can only be a simple config.  Try comparing the network configs of the two VMs.